# Auto enable specific WebExtension in Firefox

Tags: deployment, firefox-addon, software-distribution

I'm trying to deploy a Firefox Add-on inside our company.

The problem is that Firefox have an Auto Disable settings to avoid unwanted extensions from being installed.

I'm looking for a way to allow one specific extension to be auto enabled
without changing the settings of Firefox (I still want to avoid installing unwanted add-on's)

Comment: How are you deploying the extension? Do you have an external-to-Firefox installer? If so, what OS? Is the installer running as root/Administrator?

Comment: Currently I'm working on Windows version and I've created a script that downloads our XPI and put it in the distribution folder and the profile folder.
The installer is running as Admin